# Find char index in list

Tags: python, list, char

I want to search for a certain char (X) in a .txt file and if it is there, do a certain action. Unfortunately this code does not work:

```
file = "test.txt"
file = open(file, "r") 
lines = file.readlines()


# char in the list
if "X" in lines:
    print('X is present in the list')

# char not in the list
if "X" not in lines:
    print('X is not present in the list')
```

The test.txt file:

```
XX X XXX X XX
XXXXX XX X    XX
```

Any ideas why?

P.S.: even changing "X" to 'X' doesn't work.

Comment: What is the variable `Zeilen` in `if "X" not in Zeilen:` ?

Comment: `lines` is a list of strings. None of the lines exactly match the string `"X"`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Step through your code and see what `lines` contains. Will `'X' in lines` ever be `True`? Also `"X"` and `'X'` mean the same thing in Python.

Comment: replace ```"x" in lines ``` with ```if any("X" in words for words in lines):```. it will look for x in string inside the list

Comment: Zeilen was just a translation mistake, sorry. I just renamed the variables for you in english

Comment: @PaulM. But what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know the line number where `X` appears:

```
target = 'X'
counter = 0
with open('testing.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if target in line:
            counter += 1
            print('target is present in line {}'.format(
                i+1))

print('target appears in {} lines'.format(counter))
```

If you also need to know the column number where `X` appears:

```
target = 'X'
counter = 0
with open('testing.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        for j, char in enumerate(line):
            if target == char:
                counter += 1
                print('target is present in line {} at column {}'.format(
                    i+1, j+1))

print('target appears {} times'.format(counter))
```

---

A few clarifications:

- `with ... open` closes the file automatically when it is done, so you don't need to remember to close it explicitly
- `for i, line in enumerate(f):` iterates over the lines one by one without loading them all into memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

Since `readlines()` is a list you need to iterate and check in lines. May be you can use `for else` for this purpose:

```
file = "testing.txt"
file = open(file, "r") 
lines = file.readlines()

# char in the list
for line in lines:
    if "X" in line:
        print('X is present in the list')
        break
else:
    print('X is not present in the list')
```

It iterates over each line and if any line has character `break` is called `else` only runs if character is not found in any lines.

## Update

If you want to count, then you can simply increase counter while in loop and once loop is complete check the counter:

```
file = "testing.txt"
file = open(file, "r") 
lines = file.readlines()

# char in the list
counter = 0
for line in lines:
    if "X" in line:
        counter += 1  # < -- count
        
if counter: # check    
    print('X is present in the list')
        
else:
    print('X is not present in the list')
```

Comment: ok, that program works, but how can I can I check how often "X" is in the list?

This does not work:
``````

file= "test.txt"
file= open(file, "r")
lines= file.readlines() 

counter = 0
for line in lines:
    if "X" in line:
        counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
````

Answer (score 0):

As you asked I will have an output as a list with an item `Yes, there are 3 X's`.

I have my `dataf.txt` file:

```
XXX X XX X XX
X ASD X F FFFF XX
D X XXX X EFX
A F G
```

Reading data into file and calculating number of X's (Note: I have used the list comprehension hack!)

```py
with open('dataf.txt','r') as fl:
    data = fl.readlines()
    a = ['Yes, there are '+str(i.count('X')) + " X's" if 'X' in i else "No X's" for i in data]
    print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
["Yes, there are 9 X's", "Yes, there are 4 X's", "Yes, there are 6 X's", "No X's"]
```

Comment: List comprehensions are very much a recommended way to create lists and not a _hack_

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes but I like calling it a hack :)